# Present a thumbnail image of a remote web site page in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, thumbnails

I have been presented with the following requirement:

The user wants to type a link into a text box.
Once he hits an OK button he would like a thumbnail of the web site (the link he just entered) to be presented in a div in the current web page. (For simplicity assume that the link exists)

The site is written in asp.net mvc and jquery. ( we can not use an asp.net control)

Any ideas will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance and be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Website_URL_Screenshot.aspx) on CodeProject useful. It explains how to generate a thumbnail screenshot of a website.

---

UPDATE:

Here's a sample implementation. Start by writing a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail(string address)
{
    // TODO: Read the article I've linked about this component
    byte[] thumbnail = SomeSuperComponentThatTakesScreenShot(address);
    return File(thumbnail, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Now all that's left is to do the plumbing:

```
$(function() {
    $('#preview').click(function() {
        // When the preview button is clicked
        // get the address that the user entered:
        var address = $('#addressInput').val();

        // and generate a dynamic image inside a result div:
        var previewUrl = '<%= Url.Action("thumbnail") %>?address=' + 
                          encodeURIComponent(address);
        $('#result').html('<img src="' + previewUrl + '" alt="thumbnail" />');

        // Cancel any default actions and stop event propagations on the 
        // #preview button/link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I read that article about half an hour ago please note that it is using the asp.net image control that I can not use.

Comment: @Julian, you just want to copy paste without putting any effort? The article illustrates how to write an HTTP handler which will take a screenshot of a web address and send it to the response stream as image. You could adapt it to use a controller action which streams the image to the response and then simply generate an `<img>` pointing to this controller action and passing as parameter the web address you would like to get the screenshot of. The difficult part really is to have a component which given a web address will return you an image. Once you have this the other part is easy peasy.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, great! only in MVC I get the following `ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.`, any solutions?