# Asp .Net C# for Web Page print screen

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to take a screenshot with ASP.net C#, or can we take screenshot of any URL?

Comment: Take a quick think about the security implications if that were possible.

Comment: @JustinHarvey I believe that he wants to take a screenshot of the page just like some sites does to create a thumbnail of what is behind a link (just like google is doing now)

Comment: (+1) Agree with @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior.if it is that we think,so this is good question. BarısSamedHalıcı, If we think right, please edit your question.

Comment: Screenshot to me means the screen (as opposed to browser), hence my comment.

Comment: Why downvoting this question? This is possible with ASP.NET. You may find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot) link useful, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381775/present-a-thumbnail-image-of-a-remote-web-site-page-in-an-asp-net-mvc-applicatio) is a possible duplicate on your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture screenshot of a webpage and get Image (ASP.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362191/capture-screenshot-of-a-webpage-and-get-image-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net runs on the web server so there is not way to take a screen shot of the client.

you should use java script and perhaps an ActiveX control to achieve that.

I would not recommend you to go down this road anyway

what you can it to store the content of the page (if this can help) doing something like the below

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.gooogle.com");
```

You can then create and .html file which will look like that page

Comment: According to my comment it IS possible to take a screen shot with ASP.NET @Massimiliano Peluso

Comment: @avb1994 that solution is just a work around (basically like mine but more complex)
The web server cannot access the client to take a print screen

Comment: the webserver cannot access his own client, but other clients he can, have a look at [this](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-generate-webpage-thumbmail-screenshot-image.aspx) link, I don't see any client-code like javascript. And I think Barış Samed Halıcı only wants to make a screenshot of ANOTHER website, so I think it would be possible. else it wouldn't indeed.

Comment: I didn't look at the source code but I'm sure what ever is does it uses the HTML source of the page to generate the image.
This is a work around (as I said on my previous comment).